# Upgrade to 13.10 from 13:04 fails with 403 Forbidden

Tags: upgrade, 13.10

I have currently Ubuntu 13.04 installed.

I ran the updater and 13.10 was noted as an upgrade. After initiating the upgrade, this error message is returned and the upgrade process ends:

```
403 Forbidden file type or location: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement.html?lang=en_CA&os=ubuntu&ver=13.10
```

Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a link to a welcome page (you can open the [link](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement.html?lang=en_CA&os=ubuntu&ver=13.10) on a browser). It was probably inaccesible at the moment you upgraded